# Spring boot 1.4 logging on external tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, spring-boot

I'm having a trouble deploying spring boot war file on external tomcat. The problem is that I use the default logging I (just set the logging.file=custom.log property). it works well inside STS with the embedded tomcat; however, when deploying on external tomcat, no log file is created.

Update:
i added a logback-spring.xml and it works fine on embedded tomcat but not on external (it doesn't create the file)

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41333281/spring-boot-1-4-logging-on-external-tomcat/47407781#47407781 maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `logback-spring.xml` used in my project and it works well with external Tomcat.

```
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

And in `application.yml` file:

```
logging.file: "/var/logs/tomcat/application.log"
```

=====Edited:

I would also use `springProfile` in logback config to separate the configs for running locally from running in production; this way I can get logs in IDE's console during development:

```
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

  <springProfile name="local">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
  </springProfile>

  <springProfile name="prod">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
  </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps described at [enter link description here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) e.g. let your Application class extend SpringBootServletInitializer?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```